# Trusted Application API : Presence

Tags: skype-for-business, skypedeveloper, ucwa

Is it possible (or is it planned soon? roadmap?) using the Trusted Application API to get the presence changes from users of an O365 group? (as in UCMA).
With webhooks instead long polling(UCWA)?

What is the webEventChannel ( notifications) in Trusted Application API (github).
What kind of notifications we can get via the webhooks?

Also would be able to use the Trusted API to change the presence of other users as in UCMA? without user credentials. as  trusted application endpoint?