# Microsoft Graph API, app-only permissions

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible an application with app-only permissions to change the availability (Presence's state) of group users?

Reading the [known issues](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/known_issues) for "Group conversations, events" delegate permissions are needed. So it seems not possible.

Any other way?

(BTW UCWA is not a way as it needs also user's credentials AFAIK.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment there is no support for Skype or Skype for Business within Microsoft Graph. I recommend visiting the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and adding this suggestion.

You can find the current set of Skype API's at the [Skype Developer Platform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/skypedeveloperplatform) site. I think you may be looking for the [Trusted Application API (Public Preview)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/trusted-application-api/docs/overview) which brings a lot of the UCMA functionality to Skype for Business Online.

Comment: I was depending in the Trusted Application API, last year (from MS Ignite 2016). Really, this API is the appropriate way. But it seems that the development has stalled last 4-5 months. They don't even answer in relevant questions, neither in GitHub, neither in SO  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46187178/trusted-application-api-presence      In MS Ignite 2017 in the BRK2197 there was a mention for Trusted Services, but nothing else. I've clients asking for online Skype users and such services and I don't know what to say to them.